# no uncountable set can be a subset of a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was reading Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd Ed."  I don't quite follow the author's remark after stating and proving Theorem 2.8.  Specifically, on page 26, we have

**2.8 Theorem** $\quad$ *Every infinite subset of a countable set A is countable.*

$\quad$ **Proof** $\quad$ Suppose $E \subset A$, and $E$ is infinite.  Arrange the elements $x$ of $A$ in a seqeuence $\{x_n\}$ of distinct elements.  Construct a sequence $\{n_k\}$ as follows: Let $n_1$ be the smallest positive integer such that $x_{n_1}\in E$.  Having chosen $n_1, ..., n_{k-1}$ $(k=1,2,3,...)$, let $n_k$ be the smallest integer greater than $n_{k-1}$ such that $x_{n_k}\in E$.  Putting $f(k)= x_{n_k}\:(k=1,2,3,...)$, we obtain a 1-1 correspondence between $E$ ane $J$ (the set of positive integers).

(And then comes the following remark that I don't see how it is implied by the theorem above.)

*The theorem shows that, roughly speaking, countable sets represent the "smallest" infinity: No uncountable set can be a subset of a countable set.*

I can understand the theorem and its proof, but I don't quite see the connection between the theorem and the remark.  I'd appreciate if someone can point it out for me.

Comment: There is no infinity strictly less than countable. That is, any infinite set must be at least countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of 'infinite': (1) countably infinite, and (2) uncountably infinite.

These are the only two kinds of infinite sets, since the second is simply "all infinite sets which aren't countable".

We have the implication 
$$\text{$A$ an infinite subset of countable set} \implies \text{$A$ is countable}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\text{$A$ an infinite subset of countable set} \implies \text{$A$ not uncountable}$$
and the contrapositive of this is
$$\text{$A$ uncountable} \implies \text{$A$ not infinite subset of countable set}$$
or simply
$$\text{$A$ uncountable} \implies \text{$A$ not subset of countable set}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out!  So $A$ is uncountable $\Longrightarrow$ $A$ is not countable $\Longrightarrow$ $A$ is not a (infinite) subset of a countable set.  Hence $A$ (an uncountable set) can't be "smaller" than a countable set, i.e. a countable set is the "smallest" infinite set, roughly speaking.

Comment: Precisely.  On the other hand, every infinite set has a countably-infinite subset.

Answer (score 1):

Also roughly speaking, think about $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$.  You know that $\mathbb{Q}$ contains countably infinitely many elements. All of these elements are contained in $\mathbb{R}$, but so are the irrationals. They both contain infinitely many elements, but it is like $\mathbb{R}$ has "more." This theorem implies that in a more rigorous way.  It is saying, if a set is countably infinite, it can only contain infinite subsets that are countable, not subsets that are uncountably infinite. In a manner of speaking, $\mathbb{R}$ would be too "big" to fit in $\mathbb{Q}$.